# What's the best way to enumerate log/sign in attempts?

Tags: passwords, authentication, http

For sign in via a website, what is the best way to count the number of attempts that is:

- least vulnerable to tampering
- reliable
- quick

The system would:

- use HTTPS throughout the sign on phase (at least)
- use some kind of time dependant hashing like BCrypt
- use cookies for storing sessions
- use a database for storing the user's details, including things like last login time

I see, for example, some sites use a number as a query parameter in url. I wouldn't use this personally, but there may be some reason I can't see for this, hence the question.

Forgive me if this has been covered elsewhere on the site, I wanted to keep this quite a narrowly scoped question and it may have been touched on somewhere else, but I haven't found it. Links will be more than welcome, as will any insights or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *at least* implement attempt counting at a per-account and per-IP level, so that password cracking is blocked regardless of whether it's one account and lots of passwords, or lots of accounts and a few common passwords.

The best way to do the count is to log the attempts to a database table, then compute the count at runtime using a query. You could use a set of queries like this to compute the counts:

```
// get the last successful login time.
// if this returns no rows, default it to 2000-01-01 00:00:00 or similar
SELECT TOP(1) attempt_time AS last_success_time
FROM login_attempts
WHERE success = 0

SELECT MAX(tmp.attempt_count) AS attempt_count // we want the highest count
FROM (

  SELECT COUNT(*) AS attempt_count
  FROM login_attempts
  WHERE
    attempt_time > $last_success_time // only count from the last successful login
    and success = 0
    and ip_address = $ip; // count by IP

  UNION

  SELECT COUNT(*) AS attempt_count
  FROM login_attempts
  WHERE
    attempt_time > $last_success_time // only count from the last successful login
    and success = 0
    and user_id = $uid; // count by user ID

) tmp;
```

Another thing to watch out for is proxies. Most people worry about them and attempt to use headers such as `X-Forwarded-For` to block source IPs. The problem with this is that `X-Forwarded-For` can be set by an attacker and used to get any IP address banned, simply by failing to log in. As such, you should check for *existing* bans based on `X-Forwarded-For` and the source IP, but never set new bans based on the header. This means that users attempting to evade bans by using a proxy will be caught if the proxy supplies `X-Forwarded-For`, but attackers can't spoof via it. It also has the side-effect of banning proxies that are used for attacks, which is a nice bonus.